# Checking For Empty Array in If/Else Block Strange Behavior

Tags: reactjs

Within my if/else block, I wanted to check if a certain array is empty by using:

```
else if (emptyFieldNames.length === 0) {
  console.log('no empty fields');
}
```

I've consoled log 'emptyFieldNames' and can verify it is empty, but the code body won't run**.

If you fill in all input fields [here in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/BgwGGB?editors=0111), and click submit, you'll see it console logging an empty array, but yet not logging the message. The interesting part is, **if you fill in a valid email, it will console log the message. However, I don't see why that would matter since array is still empty whether or not a valid email is inputted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Log `this.state.errors` as well. `setState` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your codepen doesn't quite match the code you've posted here, but the general gist of what you're seeing is that your `else/if` statement comes after an `if (this.state.errors.email === true)` block. So if there are email errors, they're going to take precedence over not having values entered for the other inputs.

Here's what you have now:

```
if (this.state.errors.email === true) {
  invalidEmailMessage.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
  this.setState({
    errors: {
      email: true,
    },
  });
} else if (emptyFieldNames.length > 0) {
  failMessage.innerHTML =
    'Please complete the following field(s): ' + emptyFieldNames.join(', ');
  invalidEmailMessage.innerHTML = '';
} else if (emptyFieldNames.length === 0) {
  console.log('All fields have data');
}
```

If you want to have the second block get run in addition to mentioning the email errors, you might want to remove the `else` keyword. Or, if you want an empty email field to simply override any other email errors, you might want to move that conditional block to the top, and handle email errors in an `else/if` later.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at

```
this.setState({
    inputs: {
       email: emailInput,
    },
    errors: {
        email: !emailValid,
    },
});
```

You misunderstood the `setState` function, it is a 1st level merge...
So now, you just have email in inputs and email in error.
In the `else`, it seems good...

Then you use query selector and other from DOM in `handleSubmit`, it is not the way to do, use values in `this.state`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you asked but I'd like to share with you another way to work.
Starting from that, you can go to a form builder, just taking the inputs definition in props

```
const emailRegexp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const emailValidation = (email) => emailRegexp.test(email);
const notBlank = (value) => !!value.trim();

class Page extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name : {
                type: 'text',
                label : 'Name',
                value : '',
                validation : notBlank,
                error : false
            },
            email : {
                type: 'text',
                label : 'Email',
                value : '',
                validation : emailValidation,
                error : false
            },
            message : {
                type: 'textarea',
                label : 'Message',
                value : '',
                validation : notBlank,
                error : false
            }
        };
    }

    onChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        let error = !this.state[name].validation(value);

        let input = Object.assign({}, this.state[name], {error, value});
        this.setState({ [name] : input });
    };

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let hasError = false;

        let newState = Object.assign(this.state);

        Object.keys(this.state).forEach( k => {
            newState[k].error = !newState[k].validation(newState[k].value);
            hasError = true;
        });


        if( hasError) return this.setState(newState);

        //Here, well do what you want, call an API...
    };

    render() {
        let errors = Object.values(this.state).filter( i => i.error );


        return (
            <div>
                <ul className='errors'>
                    {
                        Object.values(this.state).filter( i => i.error ).map( invalid => <li key={invalid.name}>Enter a valid {invalid.label}</li>)
                    }
                </ul>
                <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    {
                        Object.keys(this.state).map( k => {
                            let input = this.state[k];
                            //Do with className but no css here
                            let style = {};
                            if(input.error) style.color='red';
                            return (
                                <label key={k} style={style}>
                                    <span>{input.label || k}</span>
                                    {input.type === 'textarea' && <textarea
                                            name={k}
                                            onChange={this.onChange}
                                            value={input.value}
                                        />
                                    }
                                    {input.type === 'text' && <input
                                            type={input.type}
                                            name={k}
                                            onChange={this.onChange}
                                            value={input.value}
                                        />
                                    }
                                    {input.error && <span>{input.error}</span>}
                                </label>
                            );
                        })
                    }

                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```